# JMeter Recording - Response Body returns "certificate_unknown"

Tags: jmeter

I'm using the Recording Controller and proxy with BlueStack. I've also tried my own phone. I see these errors in my Response Body inside JMeter.

I've already downloaded the JMeter CA Cert to BlueStack and my Phone. So I'm wondering if these messages mean my JMeter Cert is in error?  or my connection to the external website is in error?

How do I solve this?

Thanks very much!

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:841)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:932)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr.parse(HttpRequestHdr.java:157)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:214)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

1. add the below line to the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your app [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. create `network_security_config.xml` file in your app [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) folder and use the following code there:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. Compile your app in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
4. Install the newly compiled app onto emulator or device
5. You should be able to record now

See [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) guide for more details